# unable to install tomcat 7 as a service on windows 2012

Tags: tomcat, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install tomcat 7 as a service on a windows 2012 server using the command:

```
service.bat install
```

I get the following error message:

> Access denied

I'm running from a command prompt as Admin, I am an admin on the server.  It installed just fine when I ran it on my laptop under windows 7.  Any idea why I get access denied?

Comment: do you have read and write access on the folder you are trying to install?

Comment: maybe run cmd "As Administrator" and then trry to run your script

Comment: I confirmed both read/write permissions and ran as administrator.  The solution was to merely download and install the windows 64 installation .exe.  That ran without a glitch

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed both read/write permissions and ran as administrator. The solution was to merely download and install the windows 64 installation .exe. That ran without a glitch